# Star Wars reference in Mosquito Coast?

Tags: star-wars, reference, mosquito-coast-tv

In season 1 of the show [*Mosquito Coast*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mosquito_Coast_(TV_series)) (2021) S01E02 "Foxes and Coyotes", the Fox family hire two coyotes to smuggle them across the border into Mexico. The driver, named Juan, makes a reference to [*Star Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film)) (1977) after the son questions whether the truck they are in can handle the terrain.

> Juan: She may not look like much, but she's got it where it counts, kid.

Han Solo's remark to Luke in *Star Wars: A New Hope* (1977) in reference to the Millennium Falcon.

We later learn that the other coyote who rides shotgun is named Chuy, pronounced "Chewy". This to me seems like another obvious Star Wars reference, however the character's name is in fact Chuy, not an alias. It also occurred to me that the name Juan is very close to Han.

I immediately took to the internet to see if I could confirm my findings that this was an intended reference to Star Wars but I can not find even a blog post where anyone else noticed the same thing, which seems strange to me. So I thought I'd ask here if anyone has heard of this being an intended reference by the show runners?

Comment: Well, Harrison Ford was in the film version.  There's a reference right there!

Comment: It almost has to be a reference. The quote is exact, IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

It is an intended reference, there is a [trivia mention on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13056672/trivia/).

> Juan quotes a line from *Star War*s that was spoken by Han Solo. Han Solo was portrayed by Harrison Ford who also starred in the movie version of Mosquito Coast.

[Harrison Ford played Allie Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mosquito_Coast_(film)) in the 1986 movie, so it seemed fitting to insert a Star Wars reference into the TV series.

> *The Mosquito Coast* is a 1986 American drama film directed by Peter Weir and starring Harrison Ford, Helen Mirren, Andre Gregory, and River Phoenix. It is based on the 1981 novel of the same name by Paul Theroux.